# Disabling busy cursor for eclipse Job

Tags: eclipse, runnable, jobs

This code does what I need, with the exception that there is a quick switch between the normal cursor, and the busy cursor happening extremely fast.

```java
    /* this code is run inside the createPartControl(Composite parent) method of a ViewPart */
    Job job = new Job("refreshing")
    {
        @Override
        protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor)
        {

            while (data.isReading())
            {
                Display.getDefault().syncExec(new Runnable()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {

                        treeViewer.setInput(DataView.this.dataModel.getArray());

                    }

                });
            }

            return Status.OK_STATUS;
        }
    };
    job.schedule();
```

So is there a way of disabling the busy cursor of a Job in eclipse?
Also, could this happen because the Job is called in a GUI class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call

```java
job.setSystem(true);
```

before you schedule the job. From the JavaDoc:

> Sets whether or not this job is a system job. System jobs are
>   typically not revealed to users in any UI presentation of jobs. Other
>   than their UI presentation, system jobs act exactly like other jobs.
>   If this value is not explicitly set, jobs are treated as non-system
>   jobs. This method must be called before the job is scheduled.

However I think the busy cursor is coming from the `BusyIndicator.showWhile` call in `AbstractTreeViewer.createChildren` which the tree `setInput` will call. I don't think you can do anything about.

Comment: The difference now is that the Job does not appear in the Progress view. But I get the same cursor flickering between arrow and busy. :(

Comment: Then I don't think the busy cursor is coming from the Job.

Comment: I see. So maybe it comes from a method that I am calling in the while loop. I think that it might come from the repeated call of Display.getDefault().syncExec(). I'll look further into that.

Comment: Possibly coming from the `BusyIndicator.showWhile` call in `AbstractTreeViewer.createChildren` - which I don't think you can do anything about.

Comment: Oh, right. Previously I was using a TableViewer for the same purpose and maybe that's why I didn't encounter this problem then.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that. Using a TableViewer instated of a TreeViewer solves this issue.